# Why does `QDateTime` implement implicit sharing?

Tags: c++, performance, qt

[According to the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) implicit sharing is done mostly for performance (avoiding copies and automatic copy-on-change).

Why is it implemented for the class `QDateTime` that should apparently be just a small amount of bytes? I'd say that the cost of heap allocation and thread synchronization for reference counting update would exceed by a lot the small gain of not copying a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It is cheaper.

Long answer: Qt is designed around the [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) pattern. Creating a real copy of an object means that you have to allocate new heap for the PIMPL and copy both. Especially the new allocation is rather expensive for small objects. To overcome this problem they decided to implement copy-on-write for many even small classes.

Comment: Not all Qt is done with PIMPL; two trivial - and related - counterexamples are `QDate` and `QTime`, which are "regular" classes having their data straight in their `private:` section. How is `QDateTime` any different?

Comment: @MatteoItalia QDate and QTime both don't attempt to deal with timezones, so they can be fully represented by a single number, and there's no real reason that this would ever change, so PIMPL is pretty useless, and it's objectively better to have them on the stack. QDateTime does deal with timezones which adds complexity. Also, there's bound to be at least a QString in there to store the timezone name, so heap allocation is already used and getting rid of it isn't a huge optimisation.

Comment: @JosephIreland `QDateTime` does contain a  `QTimeZone`, but it is in turn a `QSharedDataPointer`-based class, which is usually empty (so, there's no allocation to do) or it is a shared copy from somewhere else (and it's immutable, so it's not like you can detach it in any way). If `QDateTime` weren't dptr-based there would never be any heap allocation anyway.

Comment: The only problem I see is that the `QTimeZone` support is conditional, so PIMPL for `QDateTime` (which may or may not include `QTimeZone`) may be useful if it was necessary to maintain ABI compatibility between applications compiled against a Qt version _without_ timezones support and a library version providing it. But then again, it would be trivial to add a dummy `QTimezone` version instead.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thats true, but there's also status flags and daylight savings information which I guess the devs considered complex enough to warrant PIMPL.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have helped though, reading the source it seems they've locked a lot of their implementation into serialisation code, so maybe a mistake to use PIMPL here. It's hard to complain though since Qt is so good with binary compatibility, they're more concerned with that than minor performance gains.